# How to install 3ds max 2009 on ubuntu using wine

Tags: wine

I see on winehq.org website is Gold support for 3ds max 2009 application.

But when I install it alert me that the .NET 2008 SP1 is error and I cannot continue to install this program.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing ***.NET 2008 SP1*** *after install* ***3ds max 2009***

Comment: Can you provide information about how to obtain and install this? It should be possible to *attempt* to install it in Wine, but does anything special need to be done? (Even if not, you can still include a link to where .NET 2008 SP1 may be downloaded.)